# Knex.js insert from select

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I'm trying to generate a query like the following via Knex.js:

```sql
    INSERT INTO table ("column1", "column2")
    SELECT "someVal", 12345
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM table
        WHERE "column2" = 12345
    )
```

Basically, I want to insert values only if a particular value does not already exist. But Knex.js doesn't seem to know how to do this; if I call `knex.insert()` (with no values), it generates an "insert default values" query.

I tried the following:

```js
    pg.insert()
        .into(tableName)
        .select(_.values(data))
        .whereNotExists(
            pg.select(1)
                .from(tableName)
                .where(blah)
        );
```

but that still just gives me the default values thing. I tried adding a `.columns(Object.keys(data))` in hopes that `insert()` would honor that, but no luck.

Is it possible to generate the query I want with knex, or will I just have to build up a raw query, without Knex.js methods?

Answer (score 8):

The most comprehensive answer I've found (with explicit column names for `INSERT`, and custom values in the `SELECT`-statement) is here:

https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1056#issuecomment-156535234

<sup>by [Chris Broome](https://github.com/chrisbroome)</sup>

here is a modified copy of that solution:

```js
const query = knex
  // this part generates INSERT-clause of the
  // query (with column-names): INSERT "tablename" ("field1", "field2" ..)
  .into(knex.raw('?? (??, ??)', ['tableOrders', 'field_user_id', 'email_field']))

  // and this part generates the "SELECT"-clause (even though it starts with `.insert`)
  .insert(function() {
    this
      .select(
        'user_id',  // select from column without alias
        knex.raw('? AS ??', ['jdoe@gmail.com', 'email']),  // select static value with alias
      )
      .from('users AS u')
      .where('u.username', 'jdoe')
   });
console.log(query.toString());
```

and the SQL-output:

```sql
insert into "orders" ("user_id", "email")
  select "user_id", 'jdoe@gmail.com' AS "email"
  from "users" as "u"
  where "u"."username" = 'jdoe'
```

using this approach one can for example fill a "profile"-table from pre-defined "templates"-table (`select from template`), and at the same time merge the template data with user preferences/other values (like `NOW()`).

---

another one approach (by Knex developer): https://github.com/knex/knex/commit/e74f43cfe57ab27b02250948f8706d16c5d821b8#diff-cb48f4af7c014ca6a7a2008c9d280573R608 - also with `knex.raw`

Comment: This worked beautifully, if you have to specify columns which is most likely the case, this is the way.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the select needs to be passed into the insert:

```
pg.insert(knex.select().from("tableNameToSelectDataFrom")).into("tableToInsertInto");
```

Also in order to select constant values or expressions you'll need to use a knex.raw expression in the select:

```
knex.select(knex.raw("'someVal',12345")).from("tableName")
```

This is my first post and I didn't test your specific example but I've done similar things like what you're asking using the above techniques.

Comment: sometimes I have very good default values in the target table (or auto-generated fields), so I need to list the column names for inserting. and in your example this block `pg.insert( ...)` assumes that the provided `knex.select` will return values for ALL columns, and in the correct order (order of columns in the table in the DB schema) — sometimes it just doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to make it work in my project and it doesn't look all that bad!

```js
        .knex
            .into(knex.raw('USER_ROLES (ORG_ID, USER_ID, ROLE_ID, ROLE_SOURCE, ROLE_COMPETENCE_ID)'))
            .insert(builder => {
                builder
                    .select([
                        1,
                        'CU.USER_ID',
                        'CR.ROLE_ID',
                        knex.raw(`'${ROLES.SOURCE_COMPETENCE}'`),
                        competenceId,
                    ])
                    .from('COMPETENCE_USERS as CU')
                    .innerJoin('COMPETENCE_ROLES as CR', 'CU.COMPETENCE_ID', 'CR.COMPETENCE_ID')
                    .where('CU.COMPETENCE_ID', competenceId)
                    .where('CR.COMPETENCE_ID', competenceId);
```

Note that this doesn't seem to work properly with the [returning](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-returning) clause on MSSQL (it's just being ignored by Knex) at the moment.